# How can I call a function from another file which contains an object defined in the main_file?

Tags: python, function, oop, methods, module

I have these two files:
main.py

```
def func_a():
    return object_a.method()


class ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method(self):
        return "k"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    object_a = ClassA()
    print(func_a())
    import file_1
```

and file_1.py

```
import main


print(main.func_a())
```

I get these errors:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Utente\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    import file_1
  File "C:\Users\Utente\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\file_1.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(main.func_a())
  File "C:\Users\Utente\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 2, in func_a
    return object_a.method()
NameError: name 'object_a' is not defined.
```

I would like to create `object_a` once by starting `main.py`, and have the `object_a` methods used by calling `func_a` from other files (which will be executed by main.py)

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__':` - this means the following code is only executed when run as a top level script - why would you expect `object_a` to be defined when it's not the case?

Answer (score 0):

since `__name__ != "__main__"`, `object_a` is never created in `main.py`. If you remove `object_a = ClassA()` from the `if` then it will run fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is confusing, because you are expecting that having run the line: `object_a = ClassA()` that `object_a` will be attached to the `main` module.

You could try adding this as your first line of `main.py`:

`print('top of main', __name__)`

You will see this line execute twice as you are expecting, but with different outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

What you should actually do to get what you want is to strip almost everything out of `main.py` except this:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    object_a = ClassA()
    print(func_a())
    import file_1
```

plus enough imports to make this bit work, plus this: `set_object_a(object_a)`

Thus `main.py` can become:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    set_object_a(ClassA())
    print(func_a())
    import file_1
```

Now everything else you had needs to go in another module all by itself like this:

```py
# notmain.py
object_a = None

def set_object_a(a):
    global object_a
    object_a = a

def func_a():
    return object_a.method()

class ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method(self):
        return "k"
```

Now you can have any other modules do this and similar:

```py
import notmain

print(notmain.func_a())
```